# Infinite fibonacci sequence

Tags: f#, functional-programming, fibonacci, lazy-sequences

I'm trying to imitate Haskell's famous infinite fibonacci list in F# using sequences. Why doesn't the following sequence evaluate as expected? How is it being evaluated?

```
let rec fibs = lazy (Seq.append 
                        (Seq.ofList [0;1]) 
                        ((Seq.map2 (+) (fibs.Force()) 
                                       (Seq.skip 1 (fibs.Force())))))
```

Comment: It should be noted that Haskell lazy lists are different from F# sequences (lazy lists are kept in memory when evaluated while sequences are recomputed when you iterate over them). This makes the Haskell pattern slow (if you rewrite it directly) or ugly (if you add caching for performance).

Comment: @TomasPetricek To clarify: You mean the F#-implementation of the Haskell pattern is slow or ugly, no? (Also, adding `Seq.cache` to @kvb's solution doesn't seem too bad to me?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your code still isn't lazy enough: the arguments to `Seq.append` are evaluated before the result can be accessed, but evaluating the second argument (`Seq.map2 ...`) requires evaluating its own arguments, which forces the same lazy value that's being defined.  This can be
worked around by using the `Seq.delay` function.  You can also forgo the `lazy` wrapper, and `list`s are already `seq`s, so you don't need `Seq.ofList`:

```
let rec fibs = 
    Seq.append [0;1]
        (Seq.delay (fun () -> Seq.map2 (+) fibs (Seq.skip 1 fibs)))
```

However, personally I'd recommend using a sequence expression, which I find to be more pleasant to read (and easier to write correctly):

```
let rec fibs = seq {
    yield 0
    yield 1
    yield! Seq.map2 (+) fibs (fibs |> Seq.skip 1)
}
```

Comment: I think you need `let rec fibs = Seq.cache <| seq { ...` to properly emulate the Haskell original: Haskell is call-by-need and so never re-computes previously computed values of a recursively defined sequence. I don't think you get the first n numbers in O(n) time otherwise.

Comment: Speaking of which, what is the complexity of the above solution?

Comment: This is a good answer. I had trouble understanding how the 1st example and the 2nd example were the same though. This comment in the source code I thought was somewhat helpful to understand though: https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/37a100b7caafde0f4df5a1924c9f65f4a18277a8/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L488.

Answer (score 6):

To add to `kvb`'s answer, you can also use `Seq.unfold` to generate a (lazy) sequence:

```
let fibs = Seq.unfold (fun (a, b) -> Some(a+b, (b, a+b))) (0, 1)
```

*val fibs : seq<int>*

Answer (score 3):

Yet another way:

```
let rec fib = seq { yield 0; yield! Seq.scan (+) 1 fib }
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @kvb's answer: if you just want lazy and not necessarily the `zip` trick, you can do this:

```
let fibs = Seq.unfold (fun (m,n) -> Some (m, (n,n+m))) (0,1)
```

This makes `Seq.take n fibs` run in time O(n).